# input type = time clear field in safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I have been using

```
<input type="time">
```

I testing it in Chrome and Safari. But in safari, the clear field(cross button) is not appearing.
How to get the cross button to appear

Comment: `<input type="time">` is a very low level component. Different browser may offer different behavior. If you want to implement an experience-consistent time-input component, it is better to use a library.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers perform this function automatically with HTML5 now by using

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search..."/>
```

Here is a [live example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/kjyAF)